# How to disable the google analytics-debug js?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

I want to disable the debug log for google analytics, Below is the screenshot for of my firbug . I have not added any js for this. I have only code of google tag manager. this script is loading dynamically while loading the page.

[image]

Comment: This would be off topic as it's not about programming, but a couple things: those messages look to be from GA Debugger in which case you just disable that plugin. Alternatively, just click on another dev console output type instead of `All`, such as `Info`.

Comment: I have not added any js for this. I have only code of google tag manager. this script is loading dynamically while loading the page.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I missed the part of the console messages from Firebug, so it's not GA Debugger messages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the "Use Debug Version" option to true in your tag configuration for your Google Analytics tag within Google Tag Manager? Doing so would cause GA to load the debug version and print the messages you are seeing in your console.

While configuring your tag in Google Tag Manager, this is available under:
"More Settings -> Advanced Configuration" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjWDb.png))

Comment: I cannot find this setting the GA settings in year 2021.